# compile C code with no flag other than -o

Tags: c, compiler-warnings, flags

Im doing an assignment and the requirement instruction say "Your code should compile correctly (no warnings and errors) with no flags other -o. you should compile your code to a debug-able executable without producing any warnings or error messages. (Note that -O and -o are different flags.)"

So Im so confused what does the " **no flags other -o** " means. As far as I know, "flag is a general tool for rudimentary signalling and identification, especially in environments where communication is similarly challenging.", so does the requirement mean that we can't use any for loop ?

Comment: They are flags for the compiler, example gcc. You can see a whole list [online](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Option-Summary.html)

Comment: flags are options you give to the compiler, for instance `-o`for gcc allows to indicate the target executable/binary/.... Note the statement is strange because request debugable executable and that generally means an option, for instance `-g` for gcc, so seems incompatible with only `-o`

Comment: "flag" in this case is a command line argument to the compiler call. So: don't use any other than what you need to specify the output file.

Comment: In this context, flags are *command-line options*, so the instructor is saying you can use the `-o` (dash oh) option to gcc, but no others. You can use any C language constructs you like inside your program.

Comment: do you confirm the compiler is *gcc* ? If yes I encourage you to compile with `-Wall` to enforce problem detection

Comment: The requirement, as written, doesn't actually forbid you from compiling with flags other than `-o` (such as `-g`) - it just says your code should compile correctly and cleanly without them. The first sentence could be read as: "When using no flags other than `-o`, your code should compile correctly (no warnings and errors)".

Comment: I would agree with @Crowman, but I contend that the instructions are ambiguous.

Answer (score 3):

No, the requirement is referring to command-line flags, ie options to the compiler. Eg, assuming gcc, `gcc -o foo foo.c`.

However, since the program is meant to be debuggable, the requirements are contradictory because creating a debuggable executable requires (for gcc) the `-g` flag.

Answer (score 1):

On many compilers, you can control the warning level with flags. The requirement here is to not use those flags, yet raise no warning.

Said differently, you are just asked to write *neat and clean* C code using no specific extension nor any *semi valid* constructs (code not conforming to the standard but accepted with warnings by a compiler)